# Setting user input parameters and accounting for varying answers

Tags: python-3.x

I've managed to save input into a variable then called it in the function below it. I wanted to account for .upper() and .lower() choices such as if someone inputs "C", "c", "Circle", or "circle". Not sure how to do that though...

```
"""
a calculator that can compute the area of a chosen shape, as selected by the user. The calculator will be able to determine the area of a circle or a triangle
"""

from math import pi
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

#opening comments and thinking computer thinks for 1 second
now = datetime.now()
print("Calculator is booting up! Beep Boop...")
print(("%s/%s/%s " + "%s:%s \n") % (now.month, now.day, now.year, now.hour, now.minute))
sleep(1)

#nagging teacher comment if needed 
hint = str("Don\'t forget to include the correct units! \nExiting...")

#user input choose Circle or Triangle
option = input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ")

#Circle computing
if (option.upper() == input(str(C))) or (option.lower() == input(str(c))):
  radius = input(float("What is the radius?: "))
  area = (pi * radius ** 2)
  print("The pie is baking...")
  sleep(1)
  print(str(area + hint))
```

It's from a code academy project and tried to search for an answer but couldn't find one here

Answer (score 0):

Just lower the input you get from the user and only test against lowercase:

```
if option.lower() == expected_lowercase_input:
```

That way you don't have to worry about case at all as `'FOO'`, `'Foo'`, `'fOO'`, etc., will all be lowered to `'foo'`.

To account for variations like `'c'` or `'circle'`, you could do something like:

```
expected = ('c', 'circle')

if option.lower() in expected:
    ...
```

Which will execute the `if` block if the lowercase version of `option` is `'c'` *or* `'circle'`.

Stick with the Codecademy stuff. It is a great resource in my opinion!